# Excel to SQL (SSIS) - Importing more then 1 file, ever file has more then 1 sheet and the data from excel starts from the 3rd row

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

**Excel to SQL (SSIS) - Importing more then 1 file, ever file has more then 1 sheet and the data from excel starts from the 3rd row.**

How would you build this the best way?
I know how to do each 1 separate but together I got into a pickle.

Please help me as I haven't found Videos or sites regarding this.

Just to clarify - 
The tables (in excel) have the same design (each in different sheet).
Some excel files have 4 sheets some have only 3.

Many thanks,
Eyal

Comment: I've done this in the past with the same varying number of worksheets per Excel file.  Are all of the source Excel files located in the same folder?

Comment: Yes they are. All files are located in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the Excel files to be imported are located in the same folder, you will first create a For-Each loop in your control flow.  Here you will create a user variable that will be assigned the full path and file name of the Excel file being read (you'll need to define the .xls or .xlsx extension in the loop in order to limit it to reading only Excel files).  The following link shows how to set up the first part.

[How to read data from multiple Excel files with SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

Within this loop you will then create a another For-Each loop that will loop through all of the Worksheets in that current Excel file being read.  Apply the following link to perform that task of reading the rows and columns from each worksheet into the database table.

[Use SSIS to import all of the worksheets from an Excel file](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2531/loop-over-excel-worksheets.htm)

The outer loop will pick up the Excel file and the inner loop will read each worksheet, regardless of the number.  They key is that the format of each worksheet must be the same.  Also, using the Excel data flow task, you can define from which line of each worksheet to begin reading.  The process will continue until all of the Excel files have been read.

For good tracking and auditing purposes, it is a good idea to include counters in the automated process to track the number of files and worksheets for each that were read.  I also like to first import all of the records into staging tables where any issues and cleaning can be performed for efficiently using SQL before populating the results to the final production tables.

Hope this all helps.